# PHP 5.3 write contents to plain text

Tags: webserver, php-5.3

I am trying to make a PHP script write into a plain text file.  I have done this before and it worked just fine.  But it's not working this time for some reason.
Here is the HTML I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/feedback.css" >
        <title>Questions, Comments, Suggestions</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="title">Questions, comments, and suggestions here!</p>
            <form method="post" name="userFeedback" action="/submit.php">
            <textarea id="comments" placeholder="Leave a comment or review here..."></textarea>
            <textarea id="name" placeholder="Your name here"></textarea>
            <textarea id="contact" placeholder="Put any means of contact you want to here (optional)"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input class="enter" type="submit" value="Enter">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

All I want to do with this is to print out whatever is entered onto a plain .txt file with PHP 5.3.  Here is the code:

```
$data = ($_POST["comments"] ." || ". $_POST["name"] ." || ". $_POST["contact"]);
    $data = strip_tags($data);

    $file = "feedback.txt";
    $f = fopen($file, "a+");

    fwrite($f, $data . "\n" . "\n");

    fclose($f);

    header ( 'Location: index.html' );
```

Please remember that I am using 5.3.  I'm sure there's a simple error in here somewhere. Can someone help me with this?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We got it!  Turns out that the PHP $_POST method looks for the "name" attribute and not the "id".